# C, getting the maximum float or maximum double not from <float.h>

Tags: c, floating-point, max, min

i was completing book "C. Programming language", but faced up with the question in which i should get the maximum\minimum value of float-pointing number, without using any of standard libraries, such as `<float.h>`. Thank you

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks Due to the nature of floating-point, you may be waiting for a long time if you pick the wrong increment, or get a smaller maximum that the real maximum if you pick too large an increment.

Comment: Could you not perform bitwise operations to flip all the bits?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I removed my comment because I realized it wasnt quite what the question was asking

Comment: @PascalCuoq, assuming that floating point is represented as _mantissa_ / _exponent_ pair you may multiply and divide.

Comment: `float.h` is a header, not a library.

Comment: `double MaximumDouble = 1.0/0.0;`

Comment: This is a duplicate - somewhere in SO - cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Without using” exercises are a little bit stupid, so here is one version “without using” any header.

```
…
double nextafter(double, double);
double max = nextafter(1.0 / 0.0, 0.0);
…
```

And without using  any library function, only assuming that `double` is mapped to IEEE 754's binary64 format (a very common choice):

```
…
double max = 0x1.fffffffffffffp1023;
…
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a binary floating-point format, start with 2.0 and multiply it by 2.0 until you get an overflow.  This determines the maximum exponent.  Then, starting with *x* as the number you had right before the overflow, take the sum *x + x/2 + x/4 + ...* until adding *x/q* does not change the value of the number (or overflows again).  This determines the maximum mantissa.

The smallest representable positive number can be found a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia you can read up the IEEE floating point format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

This contains

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent width: 8 bits
- Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)

The page also contains information on how to interpret the exponent value. Value of 0xFF (255) in exponent signifies ±infinity if the significant is zero and NaN (not a number) otherwise. The +- infinity are largest numbers. The sign bit defines if the number if +infinity or -infinity. If the question is about the largest non-infinite value then just use the largest non-special value.

Largest non-infinite value is 24 bits of 1s in significand and 0xFE (254) as exponent. Since the exponent is offset the actual value is something like: significand * 2^(254-127) which is somewhere close to 3.402823 × 10^38 in decimal according to the wikipedia page. If you want the minimum, just toggle the sign bit on to get the exact same value as negative.

EDIT: Since this is about C, I've assumed the 32 bit IEEE float.

Comment: If OP can assume 32 bit IEEE (binary), then code can simply return `3.402823e38`.  Certainly OP is looking for a generic approach.  BTW: C does not specify `float` as `32 bit IEEE`, though it is commonly used.

Comment: @chux "it is commonly used" is a bit of understatement. And the answer does cover how you can arrive at the value. However, it is true that the OP specified only "value of float-pointing number". I would interpret this as single-precision but it can also be interpret more generally for float of any size.The current highest answer lacks here, first it uses double precision assumption AND the nextafter comes from c++ math library, while the question was for C.

Comment: The OP did not only specify "value of float-pointing number" but also in the title, last edited 5 hours before your comment which says "maximum float or maximum double". The C spec has section 7.12.11.3 "The `nextafter` functions" , so the top rated answer is legitimately using C functions.  Although that does not seem to follow OP's "without using any of standard libraries".

Comment: @chux you seem to be correct. I missed the title edit. I also missed that the C99 had the nextafter method.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the number of bits the number holds by doing a sizeof(type)*8.
Then look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

This way you can look it up in a table based in the number of bits.
This assumes that the structure is using IEEE 754.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the IEEE definition, and work from there. For example, number of bits of exponent, number of bits of mantissa. When you study the format, you will see that the 23 bits of mantissa actually represent 24 bits. The reason is, the mantissa is "normalised", that is, it is left shifted so that the ms bit is always 1. This gives the maximum number of significant bits retained from a calculation. Where has the 24th bit gone? Because it is always there (except for a `0` value), it is "implied" as the 24th bit.